# Error 'takeUntil is not a function' on all my Observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, subject

For some reason I can't use the `takeUntil` method on any of my observables.

My IDE (Visual Studio Code) shows it as a valid method while I'm coding, and it compiles fine (from typescript), but when I run it I get `takeUntil is not a function` on any of my observables.

I'm using rxjs version 5.3.0.

I can make it happen in a wide variety of ways, but this is likely the most straightforward:

```
let subject:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
let unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
subject.takeUntil(unsubscribe);
```

Honestly I can't find any way to instantiate anything where `takeUntil` doesn't result in that error, but the IDE never complains and typescript always compiles fine - the error always occurs in the browser.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you probably need to import the takeUntil operator:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';`

Comment: That seems to solve the issue.  How do you know which operators are available by default and which you have to import?  For example, `subscribe` is always there without me having to import it.  I guess I just try and if it doesn't work, I import it?  Why doesn't the build process catch the fact that the operator is missing?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good way to know except to assume that you will have to import all operators. Your IDE likely has multiple type definitions for <Observable> which contain the extended (add) functionality, so that's why you can see the extended definition.

Comment: you can also import all operators by importing rxjs/Rx instead of rxjs

Comment: @JusMalcolm you should not do it